# File path for a Cron Job

Tags: cron, cpanel

Hi I want to run a cron job to call a PHP script on my server. **I am using Cpanel** from my web host and these are the options:

- Minute:
- Hour:
- Day:
- Month:
- Weekday:
- Command:

I am really struggling to point the command to my file I am using this line `/home/abbeysof/public_html/adi/cron/daily.php` but I am getting this error:

> /bin/sh: /home/abbeysof/public_html/adi/cron/daily.php: Permission denied

I asked my web host for help and this is the response:

> If you use cpanel to create it, it will fill in the path for you. Typically /home/username/public_html/etc

Can anyone please offer some advice?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Advise 1**: use wget command, wget runs the PHP script exactly as if it was called from the web so the PHP environment is exactly the same of when calling the file from the web, it's easier to debug your script then.

```
wget -O - http://yourdomain.com/adi/cron/daily.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The cron jobs has to be created going into cPanel cron jobs menu. I don't understand if you have this clear by reading your hoster's answer.

**And advise 2**: change web hosting, try [this one](http://www.qualityhostonline.com) they don't leave you alone.

Comment: You explanation just saved my day:)
Thank you!

Comment: wget creates temporary files. Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375260/cron-command-to-run-url-address-every-5-minutes

Comment: @amilaishere you simnply need to use the `-O -` option to redirect `STD_OUTPUT` and `STD_ERROR` to blackhole `"/dev/null"` I updated the code of the question

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't know anything about cpanel, but it sounds like:

- if you created the file daily.php, then you need to change the permissions on it
- if they created the file, then there's a bug in their creation routine.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

**try this one**

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/yourCpanelUsername/public_html/filename.php
```

**for some cpanels it might be like this**

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/yourCpanelUsername/public_html/filename.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to make `/home/abbeysof/public_html/adi/cron/daily.php` executable.

Answer (score 0):

The link might help you.
https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/how-to-run-a-cron-job

There is difference if you are using VPS than sharing hosting for giving the command.
You may need to use `user-agent` & `cPanel-Cron` along with your url. 
    `curl --user-agent cPanel-Cron http://example.com/cron.php`