# CRON command to run URL address every 5 minutes

Tags: php, cron

I'm newbie in cron commands and I need help.

I have a script on `http://example.com/check/`.

Whats is command for cron to run this URL every 5 minutes?

I tried

> */5 * * * * /home/test/check.php

But I want to run URL not relative script address. How to do it?

Comment: Check out the related questions (lower right) - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830208/php-cron-job-every-10-minutes?rq=1]

Comment: I tried */5 * * * * /home/test/check.php

But I want to run URL not relative script address. How to do it?

Comment: That's a file not a URL - just perform a wget in the url

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Based on the comments try

```
*/5 * * * * wget http://example.com/check
```

**[Edit: 10 Apr 2017]**

This answer still seems to be getting a few hits so I thought I'd add a link to a new page I stumbled across which may help create cron commands: https://crontab.guru

Comment: wget will create temporary files uses like that

Comment: Edited to ensure temporary file not created (hope it's accepted, but JiC)
    `*/5 * * * * wget -qO- http://example.com/check &> /dev/null`

Comment: I would do     */5 * * * * wget http://example.com/check --delete-after to make sure there are no temporary files

Comment: And don't forget to call `sudo service cron reload` after saving the *crontab file* ;)

Answer (score 129):

Use cURL:

```
*/5 * * * * curl http://example.com/check/
```

Comment: Just a note, you should run curl without output or progress by piping to /dev/null like so. `*/5 * * * * curl -s http://example.com/check/ > /dev/null`

Comment: If any error occured on that, you could try double quotes around URL. like that <code> curl -s "http://example.com/check/" > /dev/null </code>

Answer (score 50):

The other advantage of using curl is that you also can keep the HTTP way of sending parameters to your script if you need to, by using `$_GET`, `$_POST` etc like this:

```
*/5 * * * * curl --request GET 'http://exemple.com/path/check.php?param1=1&param2=2'
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example of the wget script in action:

`wget -q -O /dev/null "http://example.com/cronjob.php" > /dev/null 2>&1`

Using `-O` parameter like the above means that the output of the web request will be sent to `STDOUT` (standard output).

And the `>/dev/null 2>&1` will instruct standard output to be redirected to a black hole. So no message from the executing program is returned to the screen.

Comment: Does it work for `https`? How to ignore SSL issues via this way?

Answer (score 3):

To run a url, you need a program to get that url. You can try [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/). See manuals for available options.

Answer (score 3):

To run a URL simply use command below easy yess CPanel 100%

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/CpanelUsername/public_html/RootFolder/cronjob/fetch.php
```

I hope this help.

Comment: /usr/bin/php -q /home/CpanelUsername/public_html/RootFolder/cronjob/fetch.php

Answer (score 3):

Nothing worked for me on my linux hosting. The only possible commands they provide are:

```
/usr/local/bin/php absolute/path/to/cron/script
```

and

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php56 absolute/domain_path/path/to/cron/script
```

This is how I made it to work:
1. I created simple test.php file with the following content:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/check/');
```

2. I set the cronjob with the option server gived me using absolute inner path :)

```
/usr/local/bin/php absolute/path/to/public_html/test.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Use perfect URL:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null "https://www.example.com/payment/WebhookOrderCron" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

I try `GET 'http://example.com/?var=value'` Important use `'` 
add `>/dev/null 2>&1` for not send email when this activate
Sorry for my English