# Using CRON jobs to visit url?

Tags: linux, web-applications, cpanel, cron-task

I have a web application that has to perform a repeated tasks, Sending messages and alerts, I, already, use a script page do those tasks when it loaded in the browser i.e http://example.com/tasks.php and I included it by the mean of iframe in every page of my web application.

Now I want to change this to use CRON jobs because the first approach may leads to jam performance, So How could I make a CRON job that visits http://example.com/tasks.php. However, I don't want this CRON job creating output files such as day.*!

I host the application on shared hosting service that permits CRON jobs via cPanel.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

```
* * * * * wget -O - http://yoursite.com/tasks.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

That should work for you. Just have a `wget` script that loads the page.

Using `-O -` means that the output of the web request will be sent to STDOUT (standard output)

by adding `>/dev/null` we instruct standard output to be redirect to a black hole. 
by adding `2>&1` we instruct STDERR (errors) to also be sent to STDOUT, and thus all output will be sent to a blackhole. (so it will load the website, but never write a file anywhere)

Comment: what are all these asterisks at the begining

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani They are part of the cron syntax: http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

Comment: The only solution that worked for me under Raspbian Stretch Lite.  Perfect! :D

Comment: One note: it's a good idea to quote the URL, if it contains a query it may not work without everything being quoted.

Answer (score 29):

You can use `curl` as is in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20267276/1506848)

For the lazy:

```
*/5 * * * * curl --request GET 'http://exemple.com/path/check.php?param1=1'
```

This will be executed every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 25):

You don't need the redirection, use only

```
* * * * * wget -qO /dev/null http://yoursite.com/tasks.php
```

Comment: Why is the redirection not needed?

Comment: `-q|--quiet      Turn off Wget's output.`

Comment: your command also use redirection but in other form -qO /dev/null, isn't it?

Comment: Strictly speaking, not a redirection as *I/O redirection* is a shell thing

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the local commandline php-cli:

```
* * * * * php /local/root/path/to/tasks.php > /dev/null
```

It is faster and decrease load for your webserver.

Answer (score 8):

**i use this commands**

```
wget -q -O /dev/null "http://example.com/some/cron/job.php" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Cron task:**

```
* * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null "http://example.com/some/cron/job.php" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: This one need some explaining, but it works very well. Especially if, like me, you have an ampersand in your URL. Putting the url inside quotes is a solution. Why do you putt /dev/null before the url ?

Comment: This is probably late reply but its never too late. 

Reason is:

**/dev/null** is a special filesystem object that throws away everything written into it. Redirecting a stream into it means hiding an output. The **2>&1** part means "redirect both the output and the error streams".

Comment: Ok so, it means that the content of wget is redirected to /dev/null (so it is basically deleted and ignored) ? Thanks

Comment: Yes output sent to **/dev/null** is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this for url with parameters:

```
lynx -dump "http://vps-managed.com/tasks.php?code=23456"
```

lynx is available on all systems by default.

Comment: -dump dumps the content of the page to file. That is a possibly undesired side effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command:

```
links https://www.honeymovies.com
```

Answer (score 2):

U can try this :-

```
    wget -q -O - http://www.example.com/ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

`* * * * * wget --quiet https://example.com/file --output-document=/dev/null`

I find `--quiet` clearer than `-q`, and `--output-document=/dev/null` clearer than `-O - > /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

For Cron job to work you just need to hit the url, without any output and without downloading anything.

I am using only the wget with this two parameters:

```
*/2 * * * * wget -q --spider https://example.com/
```

*/2 : run every 2 minutes

‘-q’ :Turn off Wget’s output.

--spider : When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider, which means that it will not download the pages, just check that they are there.

Documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example. you can use it like

> wget -q -O - http://example.com/backup >/dev/null 2>&1

and in start you can add your option like (*****). Its up to your system requirements either you want to run it every minute or hours etc.