# What is correct for auto schedulling of a job using PHP

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I have an application written in PHP and MySQL. There I need to activate calendar on a specific and again deactivate that calendar on other specified date. This process will occurs once in a year gap between 2 dates is approx 1.5 months.

how should I do this in PHP? Should I use cron jobs?

Comment: I recommend you to check the following question answer, which merges the cron-tasks with the PHP code logic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259530/using-cron-jobs-to-visit-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your requirements, I think it would be more stable to add the check "should I show the calendar" into the source code itself. When the check is well written, it should not consume measurable response time.

Having the cron job, you always will have to look at an additional thing. This could be forgotton or whatever. Have experienced that too often ;)

Example for a code that checks that:

```
$now = new DateTime();
if($now >= new DateTime('14 Mar') && $now < new DateTime('15 May')) {
    show_calendar();
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, as on shared server cron job resources consumption is also 1 issue which need to be continuous monitoring. And the process in once in year it may be unintentionally miss. But can't get your suggestion, it would be very nice if you put more lights on your thought

Comment: To be more precise actually this a admission process which take place between Mid of March to Mid of May (tentative) now this form should not active or you may say it should be hidden before admission starting date and again it should deactivate or hidden after the admission process. Is this possible. Or if there is any way to give the control to user they can activate or deactivate this form.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the approach **hek2mgl** has suggested.

or, if you want to set up a cron job then here is the url you should be using to execute your script on given time:

```
/usr/bin/php5 /your/directory/path/cron_script.php
```

To check the path:

Create an `index.php` in your root folder.

```
<?php
  var_dump(dirname(__FILE__));
?>
```

Hope this help.