# PHP Condition : Script performed by cronjob

Tags: php, cron

I have a script That should execute a piece of code only if the script is run from a cron job, but i do not know the condition *"if the script is performed by cronjob"*.

Comment: before execute a script (in header) send some query string in click event.. if query string has come its not executed in cron job or else its executed in cronjob

Comment: Why don't you just pass a parameter when running by cron job?

Comment: My hosting does not allow me to pass parameters, do not know the motivation.

Comment: create a script that passes the parameters, call that from cron...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 types of requests, from server and from remote, you can determine the different between them by variable $_SERVER.

If you run a php file from php command, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] will not be set.
Therefore, you can use:

```
if( !isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) {
    // The script is run by php command
}
```

However, if your 2 types of requests are run by php command, you would better use 2 php files, first is the normal one, while the second one will include the first one and also run specific script that will be run by cronjob.

Comment: @GiuseppeGrieco It would be nice if you make this as the answer. Thank.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this question's answer: [Using CRON jobs to visit url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259530/using-cron-jobs-to-visit-url)

However, supply the URL with a parameter that indicates it is being from the CRON Job.

```
* * * * * wget -O - http://yoursite.com/script.php?fromcron=1 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

*script.php*

```
if(!isset($_GET['fromcron']) || $_GET['fromcron'] !== 1) {
    exit(); 
}

// ...
```