# Facebook application after 30 April 2015

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook application on my website. This application publish on behalf of the registered user on his time line one post daily or weekly. The users IDs are stored in a database and using [cron jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259530/using-cron-jobs-to-visit-url) the publish is occurred. My application uses PHP SDK.

Everything was going fine, till 30 April 2015 the date at which Facebook upgraded their API.

Currently the application's publish action returns this error:

> OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to
> perform this action

In addition, during my login in the Facebook and from the same browser (I'm the admin of the app) the application's publish action works fine.

The developer's announcement and suggestions for apps is confusing, and I could not determine whether I have to change my application's source code? Or there is something easier?

Special note: the PHP SDK that I use is one file included as vendor in my website application, which is based on CakePHP 1.3.

#### Supplemental Edit

This is a screen shot of quickly reply from the Facebook, it has just taken less than 24 hr. to reply from the Facebook. In which detailed answer why they are not grant my app publish permissions. It is supported with screen shots to show my app in action and other demo screen shots about how should it going to be.

[image]

### Supplemental 2

After the second review try, it becomes clear that Facebook prevented any automated publish on the behalf of the user to his/her timeline. The question here: Is there any other way? such as automated private message to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if your application started breaking, you'll need to make modifications. What those modifications depend on what triggered that error. Your users will also need to go through a flow to authorize your application (probably for the `publish_actions` permission, from the sounds of that message).

Note that this permission now requires Facebook review your app, and if you're auto-posting for the user you're probably violating the policy at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill.

Incidentally, you should've been receiving emails about this for the last few months. Expect delays with review for the next few weeks as everyone else who didn't upgrade in preparation files tickets/review requests.

Comment: If you get a look at the edit of the question and as I mentioned, It works fine publishing to my timeline (I'm the admin of the app). Do you think that is an evidence that the app source code (i.e my CakePHP application's action that posts on the behalf of the user) does not require to be changed and it is just a matter of Facebook approval?

Comment: Ah, that's possible then. Users with a role in the app (developers, testers, admins) are exempt from review requirements. You might slip by with just approval.

Comment: I have just completed the review form and I'm waiting the response.

Comment: Well, I received a reply from the Facebook, and I'm working to fix what they are regarded. The Supplemental Edit contains a screen shot from their response

Comment: It seems that no way!