# Implement cron schedular in linux

Tags: cron

I am trying to execute a php script in my linux server. the script will run everyday at 8 am. I have uploaded my `crontab` in linux server and the php file `update1.php` Script in my crontab is given below. But this isnt updating my databse. where am i doing wrong ? Am i missing something here. Thanks in advance.

**crontab**

```
  0  8  *  *  *  http://www.mywebsite.com/update1.php
```

Comment: Cron Job does not run a URL . It runs a local file / script . In your case, you should run `update1.php` as PHP CLI. Alternatively, you can use `wget` to run the URL. These two methods are different. Choose wisely.

Comment: Any link to help me on using wget?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13259564/188331

Answer (score 0):

You can use **--spider** option of wget for this purpose.

```
0  8  *  *  *  wget --spider http://www.mywebsite.com/update1.php
```

***--spider*** indicates not to download anything (we just want to go through the pages, that’s all)

Answer (score 0):

This line/code in your crontab:

> http://www.mywebsite.com/update1.php

is not an execution of the script, it's just the url to it.  You should download the php script, and put it locally on your linux server.  That would make things simpler and much more reliable.

I would login to your linux server, use `wget` to download the script, `chmod` it to make sure it's executable, and `mv` it to wherever you want on your server:

```
wget http://www.mywebsite.com/update1.php -O update1.php
chmod 755 update1.php
mv update1.php /path/to/where/you/want/script
```

Then now that you have the script locally on your linux server, edit your crontab (`crontab -e`), and add the following line:

`0  8  *  *  * /path/to/where/you/want/script/update1.php`