# cron job to run url cpanel

Tags: cron, cpanel

i need to create cron job to run URL from Cpanel every minute
when i open the link from browser it's auto generate backup for database

i choose the common setting ( once per minute ) * * * * *
and this is the command i use but no one worked

```
GET http://example.com/backup > /dev/null
```

```
wget http://example.com/backup
```

```
curl -s http://example.com/backup > /dev/null
```

```
wget -q -O /dev/null "http://example.com/backup" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

this is my references 
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cron-job-to-call-a-web-page.60253/
[Using CRON jobs to visit url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259530/using-cron-jobs-to-visit-url)
[CRON command to run URL address every 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375260/cron-command-to-run-url-address-every-5-minutes/20267276#20267276)

Comment: Define "no one worked". Did you get an error message? Did you try the commands interactively (instead of having cron execute them) ? Have you tried redirecting the output of your commands to a log file and inspecting it?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt no error message appears i tried the link directly and it's working, how to commands interactively or redirect the output of my commands to log file and inspecting it ??

Comment: Instead of redirecting the output to /dev/null, redirect it to a log file, e.g. via `command > /tmp/cron-log.txt`

Comment: @FrankSchmitt thanks for your help, i get the error that code redirect to login page because it's required to be login to create backup , i change auth for it and working :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use this

```
wget -q -O - http://example.com/backup >/dev/null 2>&1
```

instead of

```
wget -q -O /dev/null "http://example.com/backup" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: can we also use like

`GET https://example.com/billing/?ng=console/0982995697/` ??

Comment: We had to escape any `&` characters in the command, e.g., if the URL contains parameters. Maybe just a requirement of a particular version of CPanel. The example then becomes `wget -q -O - http://example.com/backup?param=1\&param=2 >/dev/null 2>\&1`.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative try this

curl -s https://example.com/cron

don't forget to add the HTTP or HTTPS protocol[image]

Answer (score 2):

wget -q -O /dev/null "http://example.com/backup" > /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 1):

You can use "links" command like:

```
links https://www.honeymovies.com
```

Answer (score 1):

For Cron job to work you just need to hit the url, without any output and without downloading anything.

I am using only the wget with this two parameters:

```
wget -q --spider https://example.com/
```

- ‘-q’       :Turn off Wget’s output.
- --spider  : When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider, which means
  that it will not download the pages, just check that they are there. For example,
  you can use Wget to check your bookmarks:
  wget --spider --force-html -i bookmarks.html
  This feature needs much more work for Wget to get close to the functionality of real
  web spiders.

Documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.pdf